# I can ping computer on a another subnet but not vice versa

Tags: networking, laptop, desktop, ping, subnet

So I got two routers in my house one wireless(192.168.0.1) and another wired(192.168.20.1), I got my laptop(192.168.0.101) hooked up to my wireless router and my desktop(192.168.20.5) on wired router.

I can ping my desktop(192.168.20.5) from my laptop(192.168.0.101) but not vice versa. I disabled firewall on both of computers and still didn't work.

My laptop is running win7.
and my desktop is running Linux Mint 17.1.

Any help will be appreciated to solve this issue.
Thanks.

Comment: Please clarify the exact connection schema and routers models

Comment: @RomeoNinov My wireless router is Linksys and my wired router is netcomm

Comment: Those are brands, not models. And w/o proper network diagram we can only speculate. If wireless router is behind the wired one this is normal behavior as each router (home models) have firewall inside

Comment: Check routers for ability to send a PING or ICMP Echo test.  Can they ping Linux Mint?  Can your routers ping desktop?  Move laptop near desktop and connect via crossover cable.  Can they ping?  If they can ping with the direct connection, then you've strong reason to suspect a router.  Otherwise, chances are high that it's something on the Mint machine.

Answer (score 1):

The solution is to set WiFi router as a bridge, IF it is connected to the other router.  Most routers can let you configure it so it connects the wireless into an existing network instead of creating its own subnet.

Specify which router is connected to which via the WAN/LAN ports in the back.  One of the router must have its WAN connection plugged into another router's LAN port (any port that isn't WAN).