# Why can I ping an ipv6 but not an ipv4 and vice versa? (Hamachi)

Tags: windows, networking, firewall, ping, hamachi

I'm using *Hamachi LogMe-In* to connect a laptop (`A` with Win8.1) to a work computer (`B` with Win10) for SSH, both running Windows Firewall allowing SSH port 22, and the *PING.EXE*.

Somehow I got that to work. Then I tried to open a port for another python app on a different port trying to communicate for a remote computation setup, and it's not working as expected. Trying to debug I was pinging (after allowing `ping.exe` on both machines through FW) the different machines from each side, and to my surprise I found this happening.

```
# On: machine A
ping -4 <ipv4-B> 
# results in timeout!

# On: machine A
ping -6 <ipv6-B>
# OK
```

Then doing the opposite:

```
# On: machine B
ping -4 <ipv4-A> 
# OK

# On: machine B
ping -6 <ipv6-A>
# results in timeout!
```

**What is going on?**

My Hamachi machines are green on both sides so that connection seem ok. 
So I guess it must be some FW thing going on in windows. 
How can I debug and understand this?

---

*Possibly related questions (but not helpful to my case):*

- [I can ping IPv6 but not IPv4](https://superuser.com/questions/1278597/i-can-ping-ipv6-but-not-ipv4)
- [Accessing an IPv6 server with an IPv4 address?](https://superuser.com/questions/982113/accessing-an-ipv6-server-with-an-ipv4-address)
- [I can access my website using my IPv4 address but not my IPv6 address. Why?](https://superuser.com/questions/1082967/i-can-access-my-website-using-my-ipv4-address-but-not-my-ipv6-address-why)
- [Ping myself, works with ipv6 not ipv4 in Windows 7](https://superuser.com/questions/248555/ping-myself-works-with-ipv6-not-ipv4-in-windows-7)
- [RDP RemoteApp works with IPv6 but not IPv4?](https://superuser.com/questions/1148559/rdp-remoteapp-works-with-ipv6-but-not-ipv4)
- [SSH works over IPv6 but not over IPv4](https://superuser.com/questions/1224230/ssh-works-over-ipv6-but-not-over-ipv4)
- [I can ping computer on a another subnet but not vice versa](https://superuser.com/questions/877810/i-can-ping-computer-on-a-another-subnet-but-not-vice-versa)

Comment: what's the tracert output?

Comment: @Zina I get timeouts for that too, or did you have something specific in mind?

Comment: that was what I had in mind. hm, if you disable the windows firewall on both and it then doesnt work it is blocked on the route